# requestAnimationFrame() doesn't seem to work

Tags: javascript, animation, requestanimationframe, sprite-sheet

I have this code which kind of works but not really, this is my code:

```
var c = document.getElementById ("screen");
var ctx = c.getContext ("2d");

var characterX = 0;
var characterY = 0;
var srcX;
var srcY;
var sheetHeight = 280;
var sheetWidth = 864;
var frameCount = 8;
var cols = 8;
var rows = 2;
var character = new Image;
character.src = "spritesheet.png";
var width = sheetWidth / cols;
var height = sheetHeight / rows;
var currentFrame = 0;

function updateFrame() {
    currentFrame = ++currentFrame % cols;
    srcX = currentFrame * width;
    srcY = 0;
}

function drawCharacter() {
    ctx.clearRect (0, 0, c.width, c.height);
    updateFrame();
    ctx.drawImage (character, srcX, srcY, width, height, characterX, characterY, width, height)
}

setInterval (function() {
    drawCharacter();
}, 100);

function draw() {

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

basically when i run this code the character is drawn immediately which i don't understand cause i didn't call the drawCharacter(); in the draw(); yet, so it should not display the character. And if i write this

```
function draw() {
    drawCharacter();

    requestAnimationFrame(draw);
}
requestAnimationFrame(draw);
```

then the characther just runs so fast cause for some reason the setInterval is not working anymore, can anyone help me fix this?

Answer (score 0):

In the first version, your character is directly drawn not because of the `draw` function or the `requestAnimationFrame`, but because of `setInterval`, which redraw your character every 100ms.

In the second version, your character is updated really often because you call `drawCharacter` in your `draw` method, which itself is call with `requestAnimationFrame`: The `setInterval` works fine, but since it is already updated very often in the `requestAnimationFrame`, you don't see the 100ms interval.

To fix your code, I think the best is to remove either `setInterval` or `requestAnimationFrame`.

If you keep `setInterval`, then as it is coded now, you can change the speed of your character by modifying the timing you set for the `setInterval` method.

If you want your character's position to be refreshed as often as possible, but not move too fast, you may want to use `requestAnimationFrame` instead and rethink your `updateFrame` method to move your character depending on the time spent and not just ++currentFrame.